# NavBar en Laravel 8 con tailwindcss

Tags: laravel, css, tailwind

Estoy usando laravel 8 con Livewire entonces mi diseño estaba así

como lo deja por default  Laravel, Borre el contenido .. pero algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces estoy intentando hacer un menu

algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

& así es como se ve, todo amontonado como puedo ocultar ese menu?

la pagina dice que necesito Js (pero como es posible)
si la primera imagen que mostra ^el menu en donde dice MA se muestra un menu .. perfil, tokens etc ..

este es el código de la pagina

```html
<!-- This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ -->
<div class="relative bg-white">
  <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6">
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center border-b-2 border-gray-100 py-6 md:justify-start md:space-x-10">
      <div class="flex justify-start lg:w-0 lg:flex-1">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="sr-only">Workflow</span>
          <img class="h-8 w-auto sm:h-10" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-600.svg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="-mr-2 -my-2 md:hidden">
        <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Open menu</span>
          <!-- Heroicon name: outline/menu -->
          <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <nav class="hidden md:flex space-x-10">
        <div class="relative">
          <!-- Item active: "text-gray-900", Item inactive: "text-gray-500" -->
          <button type="button" class="text-gray-500 group bg-white rounded-md inline-flex items-center text-base font-medium hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" aria-expanded="false">
            <span>Solutions</span>
            <!--
              Heroicon name: solid/chevron-down

              Item active: "text-gray-600", Item inactive: "text-gray-400"
            -->
            <svg class="text-gray-400 ml-2 h-5 w-5 group-hover:text-gray-500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
          </button>

          <!--
            'Solutions' flyout menu, show/hide based on flyout menu state.

            Entering: "transition ease-out duration-200"
              From: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
              To: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
            Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-150"
              From: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
              To: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
          -->
          <div class="absolute z-10 -ml-4 mt-3 transform px-2 w-screen max-w-md sm:px-0 lg:ml-0 lg:left-1/2 lg:-translate-x-1/2">
            <div class="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
              <div class="relative grid gap-6 bg-white px-5 py-6 sm:gap-8 sm:p-8">
                <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/chart-bar -->
                  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 19v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2zm0 0V9a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v10m-6 0a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2m0 0V5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v14a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2z" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="ml-4">
                    <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                      Analytics
                    </p>
                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      Get a better understanding of where your traffic is coming from.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/cursor-click -->
                  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="ml-4">
                    <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                      Engagement
                    </p>
                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      Speak directly to your customers in a more meaningful way.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/shield-check -->
                  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m5.618-4.016A11.955 11.955 0 0112 2.944a11.955 11.955 0 01-8.618 3.04A12.02 12.02 0 003 9c0 5.591 3.824 10.29 9 11.622 5.176-1.332 9-6.03 9-11.622 0-1.042-.133-2.052-.382-3.016z" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="ml-4">
                    <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                      Security
                    </p>
                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      Your customers&#039; data will be safe and secure.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/view-grid -->
                  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2V6zM14 6a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2V6zM4 16a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2v-2zM14 16a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2v-2z" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="ml-4">
                    <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                      Integrations
                    </p>
                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      Connect with third-party tools that you&#039;re already using.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/refresh -->
                  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 4v5h.582m15.356 2A8.001 8.001 0 004.582 9m0 0H9m11 11v-5h-.581m0 0a8.003 8.003 0 01-15.357-2m15.357 2H15" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="ml-4">
                    <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                      Automations
                    </p>
                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      Build strategic funnels that will drive your customers to convert
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="px-5 py-5 bg-gray-50 space-y-6 sm:flex sm:space-y-0 sm:space-x-10 sm:px-8">
                <div class="flow-root">
                  <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-center rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <!-- Heroicon name: outline/play -->
                    <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M14.752 11.168l-3.197-2.132A1 1 0 0010 9.87v4.263a1 1 0 001.555.832l3.197-2.132a1 1 0 000-1.664z" />
                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                    </svg>
                    <span class="ml-3">Watch Demo</span>
                  </a>
                </div>

                <div class="flow-root">
                  <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-center rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <!-- Heroicon name: outline/phone -->
                    <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 5a2 2 0 012-2h3.28a1 1 0 01.948.684l1.498 4.493a1 1 0 01-.502 1.21l-2.257 1.13a11.042 11.042 0 005.516 5.516l1.13-2.257a1 1 0 011.21-.502l4.493 1.498a1 1 0 01.684.949V19a2 2 0 01-2 2h-1C9.716 21 3 14.284 3 6V5z" />
                    </svg>
                    <span class="ml-3">Contact Sales</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
          Pricing
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
          Docs
        </a>

        <div class="relative">
          <!-- Item active: "text-gray-900", Item inactive: "text-gray-500" -->
          <button type="button" class="text-gray-500 group bg-white rounded-md inline-flex items-center text-base font-medium hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" aria-expanded="false">
            <span>More</span>
            <!--
              Heroicon name: solid/chevron-down

              Item active: "text-gray-600", Item inactive: "text-gray-400"
            -->
            <svg class="text-gray-400 ml-2 h-5 w-5 group-hover:text-gray-500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
          </button>

          <!--
            'More' flyout menu, show/hide based on flyout menu state.

            Entering: "transition ease-out duration-200"
              From: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
              To: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
            Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-150"
              From: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
              To: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
          -->
          <div class="absolute z-10 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 mt-3 px-2 w-screen max-w-md sm:px-0">
            <div class="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
              <div class="relative grid gap-6 bg-white px-5 py-6 sm:gap-8 sm:p-8">
                <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/support -->
                  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M18.364 5.636l-3.536 3.536m0 5.656l3.536 3.536M9.172 9.172L5.636 5.636m3.536 9.192l-3.536 3.536M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0zm-5 0a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="ml-4">
                    <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                      Help Center
                    </p>
                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      Get all of your questions answered in our forums or contact support.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/bookmark-alt -->
                  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M16 4v12l-4-2-4 2V4M6 20h12a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="ml-4">
                    <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                      Guides
                    </p>
                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      Learn how to maximize our platform to get the most out of it.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/calendar -->
                  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="ml-4">
                    <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                      Events
                    </p>
                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      See what meet-ups and other events we might be planning near you.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/shield-check -->
                  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m5.618-4.016A11.955 11.955 0 0112 2.944a11.955 11.955 0 01-8.618 3.04A12.02 12.02 0 003 9c0 5.591 3.824 10.29 9 11.622 5.176-1.332 9-6.03 9-11.622 0-1.042-.133-2.052-.382-3.016z" />
                  </svg>
                  <div class="ml-4">
                    <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                      Security
                    </p>
                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      Understand how we take your privacy seriously.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="px-5 py-5 bg-gray-50 sm:px-8 sm:py-8">
                <div>
                  <h3 class="text-sm tracking-wide font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase">
                    Recent Posts
                  </h3>
                  <ul class="mt-4 space-y-4">
                    <li class="text-base truncate">
                      <a href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
                        Boost your conversion rate
                      </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="text-base truncate">
                      <a href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
                        How to use search engine optimization to drive traffic to your site
                      </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="text-base truncate">
                      <a href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
                        Improve your customer experience
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-5 text-sm">
                  <a href="#" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"> View all posts <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="hidden md:flex items-center justify-end md:flex-1 lg:w-0">
        <a href="#" class="whitespace-nowrap text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
          Sign in
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="ml-8 whitespace-nowrap inline-flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-base font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700">
          Sign up
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--
    Mobile menu, show/hide based on mobile menu state.

    Entering: "duration-200 ease-out"
      From: "opacity-0 scale-95"
      To: "opacity-100 scale-100"
    Leaving: "duration-100 ease-in"
      From: "opacity-100 scale-100"
      To: "opacity-0 scale-95"
  -->
  <div class="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden">
    <div class="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 bg-white divide-y-2 divide-gray-50">
      <div class="pt-5 pb-6 px-5">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
          <div>
            <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-600.svg" alt="Workflow">
          </div>
          <div class="-mr-2">
            <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
              <span class="sr-only">Close menu</span>
              <!-- Heroicon name: outline/x -->
              <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-6">
          <nav class="grid gap-y-8">
            <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-center rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50">
              <!-- Heroicon name: outline/chart-bar -->
              <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 19v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2zm0 0V9a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v10m-6 0a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2m0 0V5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v14a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2z" />
              </svg>
              <span class="ml-3 text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                Analytics
              </span>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-center rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50">
              <!-- Heroicon name: outline/cursor-click -->
              <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122" />
              </svg>
              <span class="ml-3 text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                Engagement
              </span>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-center rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50">
              <!-- Heroicon name: outline/shield-check -->
              <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m5.618-4.016A11.955 11.955 0 0112 2.944a11.955 11.955 0 01-8.618 3.04A12.02 12.02 0 003 9c0 5.591 3.824 10.29 9 11.622 5.176-1.332 9-6.03 9-11.622 0-1.042-.133-2.052-.382-3.016z" />
              </svg>
              <span class="ml-3 text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                Security
              </span>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-center rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50">
              <!-- Heroicon name: outline/view-grid -->
              <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2V6zM14 6a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2V6zM4 16a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2v-2zM14 16a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2v-2z" />
              </svg>
              <span class="ml-3 text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                Integrations
              </span>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-center rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50">
              <!-- Heroicon name: outline/refresh -->
              <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 4v5h.582m15.356 2A8.001 8.001 0 004.582 9m0 0H9m11 11v-5h-.581m0 0a8.003 8.003 0 01-15.357-2m15.357 2H15" />
              </svg>
              <span class="ml-3 text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                Automations
              </span>
            </a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="py-6 px-5 space-y-6">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-y-4 gap-x-8">
          <a href="#" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
            Pricing
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
            Docs
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
            Help Center
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
            Guides
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
            Events
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
            Security
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-base font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700">
            Sign up
          </a>
          <p class="mt-6 text-center text-base font-medium text-gray-500">
            Existing customer?
            <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
              Sign in
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

¿como puedo usar esos componentes & darle su animación?

he visto la documentación dice que tengo que usar  React, Vue o algo así .... ahmm no logro entonces entender, porque solo necesito esa animación de mostrar u ocultar el menu

al igual que otros detales como abrir un modal, cerrarlo etc .

Comment: no he visto ese componente entre los gratuitos de TailwindUI, ¿Compártenos por favor el link a la fuente para revisar qué más dice? En los comentarios del componente que pusiste sale qué clase hay que añadir o quitar  para mostrar u ocultar una sección, y así para todos los detalles que quieres implementar respecto a flyout menus, modales, etc

Answer (score 0):

A mi me pasaba lo mismo cuando quise editar las plantillas de blade, es mas recomendable publicarlas

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

Y luego editarlas a tu gusto y antojo desde la carpeta:

```
resources/views/vendor/jeetstream
```

Comment: Entonces con esto podré utilzar el Js que me está pidiendo porque los modales y efectos del select, entre desplegar las opciones de ese menu no me funcionan :d

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo esta libreria, es más facil de usar y ya cuenta con componentes, sin tener que crear uno desde el principio.

https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/

Comment: no va a cambiar, ya que es una página oficial.

Comment: Saludos @desarrolladortres, el mensaje que viste es un mensaje genérico cuando una respuesta esta marcada como "**La respuesta es solo un enlace**", en este caso la respuesta que brindas parece más un comentario, te invito a leer [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tus respuestas vayan mejorando y sean mejor puntuadas. ;)